# Collection view with segment duplicate cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a problem when I use collection view with segmentView.

I have a `viewController` which has a **segmentView** with 4 elements **( 0 => All , 1 => Photos  , 2 => Audios , 3 => videos )**
here's and example  :

[image]

And I have one **collectionView** to display the data depend on which category clicked from the **segmentController**

It's working and displaying the data and here's my **collectionView** methods to display data

```
 // MARK: Datasource collection method

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // All Items

        if segmentStatues == 0
        {
            let cellForAll = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AllItemsCell", for: indexPath) as! AllItemsCollectionViewCell

            // reset elements before declare

            cellForAll.cellImage.image = nil
            cellForAll.playBtn.isHidden = true

            cellForAll.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cellForAll.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            // When type is an image
            if sociaPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].postType == "image"
            {

                cellForAll.cellImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: sociaPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].postUrl))


            }else if sociaPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].postType == "audio"
            {

                cellForAll.cellImage.image  = UIImage(named: "recorde_icon")


            }else if sociaPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].postType == "video"
            {
                cellForAll.cellImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: sociaPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].thumbURL))
                cellForAll.playBtn.isHidden = false
            }

            return cellForAll

        }else{

            // Cell if Images or videos or audios

            let newCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "beepbeep", for: indexPath) as! userProfileImageCollectionViewCell

            // If the type is images

            if  segmentStatues == 1
            {   
                // Set image URL

                newCell.cellImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagesPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].postUrl))

                // Get image likes and comments and shares

                newCell.likeCount.text = String(imagesPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].likes_count)
                newCell.commentCount.text = String(imagesPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].comments_count)
                newCell.shareCount.text = String(imagesPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].shares_count)

            } else if segmentStatues == 3
            {
                // For Video player

             var player = newCell.customVid
            player = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VieoPlayer", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as? videoPlayer

           player?.newIntitVideoPlayer(forViewController: self, videoURL: videosPosts[indexPath.row].postUrl , videoThumbnail: URL(string: videosPosts[indexPath.row].thumbURL), onReady: nil)
                // Set video URL and Thumbnail

                // Get video likes and comments and shares
                newCell.likeCount.text = String(videosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].likes_count)
                newCell.commentCount.text = String(videosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].comments_count)
                newCell.shareCount.text = String(videosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].shares_count)

            }else if segmentStatues == 2
            {
                // Audio player
                let ad = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AudioPlayerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! AudioPlayerView
                ad.frame = CGRect(x: (newCell.contentView.frame.size.width - newCell.contentView.frame.size.height * 0.6) / 2, y: 20 , width: newCell.contentView.frame.size.height * 0.6, height: newCell.contentView.frame.size.height * 0.6)
                ad.playImageView.image = nil

                ad.tag = 6666

                newCell.contentView.addSubview(ad)

                // Set audio URL
                ad.audioPath = URL(string: audiosPosts[indexPath.row].postUrl)
                ad.viewInitialization()

                // Get Audio  likes and comments and shares
                newCell.likeCount.text = String(audiosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].likes_count)
                newCell.commentCount.text = String(audiosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].comments_count)
                newCell.shareCount.text = String(audiosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].shares_count)   

            }
            return newCell
        } 
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if self.segmentStatues == 0
        {

            return  sociaPosts.count
        }else if self.segmentStatues == 1
        {
            return imagesPosts.count
        }else if self.segmentStatues == 2
        {
            return audiosPosts.count
        }else
        {
            return videosPosts.count
        }
    }
```

I have 2 custom cells in my collection view one for all items and the other for (images - audios - videos ) view

my problem is data is displaying but cells duplicated when i change between segment in **userProfileImageCollectionViewCell**

these 2 pictures show the issue

Displaying all audios cell when i click in audio segmnet

[image]

But after I click in image or video segment cell duplicated like this

[image]

it's happen in audio - images  - videos only**(userProfileImageCollectionViewCell)**

and finally here's my userProfileImageCollectionViewCell code :

**updateded :**

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
class userProfileImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var customVid: videoPlayer!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var likeCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var shareCount: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        cellImage.sd_setImage(with: nil)
       self.customVid.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

    }
}
```

Comment: In `userProfileImageCollectionViewCell` in `prepareForReuse()` reset all the values (especially the ones that could be present in one case and not present in another). Else you can do it `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath()`, but since you have a custom file for your cell, I'd recommend to do it in `prepareForReuse()`.

Comment: A `collectionView.reloadData()` in your segmentedController action should help you.

Comment: Use just  `else` instead of `else if segmentStatues == 2` for last condition.

Comment: @Larme How can i reset my data ? specially audio and video  ?

Comment: Cell are reused, so the issue is that you add a subview in case of videos: `newCell.contentView.addSubview(player)` add a view for it, and remove it. If you scroll a lot and use 3D Hierarchy Debug, you'll see that there are a few of them above each others.

Comment: @Moriya iam reloading data every time i select segment element

Comment: Yea i see many cells in 3D Hierarchy but can you put the code to show how can i remove the videoplayer view ? @Larme

Comment: Create a UIView property for the video and instead of `newCell.contentView.addSubview(player)`, do `newCell.thatNewPropertyAddSubview(player)`. In `prepareForReuse()`, do `self.thatNewPropertyAddSubview.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })`. Use that same view for `ad` and `player`.

Comment: @Larme i add UIView property for video and did what you tell me but still have the same issue i updated my userProfileImageCollectionViewCell in my question

Comment: There is still `newCell.contentView.addSubview(player)` in your code.

Comment: updated my code but video player not working this time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123778/discussion-between-muhammed-and-larme).

Comment: you  need to clear subviews added on some state of segment (newCell.contentView.addSubview(ad))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `UICollectionViewCell` (as well as `UITableViewCell` by the way) are reused.

To put it simply :
When a cell disappear from screen when you scroll, it may come back at the top/bottom (according to the scroll direction). But it's not a new "clean" cell, it's the previous one. That's the reuse system.

So, when you did: `newCell.contentView.addSubview(ad)` you added each times a new subview without checking if there was one already. The subview where juste piling. It's easy to check it with the [3D Hierarchy Debug of XCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html).

Since you have a `userProfileImageCollectionViewCell` file, the best solution is to use `prepareForReuse()`.
Create a `IBOutlet` (let's call it `customVid`) that will add as its subview the ad/player.
In `prepareForReuse()` remove all the subview of `customVid`.
In `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do something like that:

```
var player = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VieoPlayer", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as? videoPlayer 
player?.newIntitVideoPlayer(forViewController: self, videoURL: videosPosts 
newCell.customVid.addSubview(player)
```

Replicate the same mechanism for the `ad` (you can use the same subview, it's up to you).

Now, a few suggestions not related to your issue:

Name your class starting with an uppercase: `userProfileImageCollectionViewCell` => `UserProfileImageCollectionViewCell`

I'd create methods in `userProfileImageCollectionViewCell` to make your code more readable. I don't speak Swift, so my next lines of code may not compile, but you should get the idea:

```
func fillWithVideo(videoParam video: CustomVideoClass) {
     var player = newCell.customVid
     player = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VieoPlayer", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as? videoPlayer
     player?.newIntitVideoPlayer(forViewController: NOTself, videoURL: video.postUrl, videoThumbnail: URL(string: video.thumbURL), onReady: nil)
    self.customVid.addSubview(player)
    // Set video URL and Thumbnail

    // Get video likes and comments and shares
     self.likeCount.text = String(video.likes_count)
     self.commentCount.text = String(video.comments_count)
     self.shareCount.text = String(video.shares_count)
}
```

In `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
//If it's the correct section
let video = videosPosts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as CustomVideoClass
cell fillWithVideo(video)
```

Note that it seems that you use the `UIViewController`, so you may want to add the UIViewController parameter in order to get the `newIntitVideoPlayer()` method to work, but I didn't want to put it in the previous example to keep it more simple. You may need to replace the lines:

```
cell fillWithVideo(video andViewController:self)
```

and

```
func fillWithVideo(videoParam video: CustomVideoClass andViewController viewController: UIViewController)
player?.newIntitVideoPlayer(forViewController: viewController, videoURL: video.postUrl, videoThumbnail: URL(string: video.thumbURL), onReady: nil)
```

Etc. for each part specific part. It make just easier to read what you are doing. Handle only in `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the logic (which section should get which item, etc.) and the rest to the cell that may adapt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your explaination :))